# Globals in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, global-variables

I've seen that people freak out when someone uses global variables in PHP.

Are they just as bad in nodejs?

Here's an example:

```
function my_app(){
    // ....
}    

my_app.prototype = {
  method_1: function(){
      // .......
  }
}

var my = my_app();
```

so `my` is global now. And I can use it in other classes that I define below without having to pass it to the constructor. I'm not even sure that it's called constructor in javascript :|

But this seems natural to me. It's basically the same way ppl access outside variables from functions defined inside functions, right?

in PHP this would look like:

```
<?php

class my_app{
..............
}

$my = new my_app();
```

Here $my has to be declared with the global keyword to be available inside functions or classes, but other than that it's the same thing

Comment: Global state is ugly in any language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is not global in node.js, it is global to that module only. If you want to make it global to all modules, put it in the global namespace.

```
global.my = 'this one is truly global';
```

You should definitively avoid globals, like in any other programming language.

Comment: so global to modules only is ok?

Comment: Inside your module they are simply called private variables. Like in any programming language, private variables make sense for internal stuff you don't want to expose your module consumers to. Dependency injection is definitely the way to go in your example, though. You should strive to limit dependencies between your classes as much as possible so it is easier to test and to refactor.